# Is celebrating death day allowed?

Tags: halal-haram, death, celebration

Birthdays are not allowed in Islam, likewise I would like to know is it allowed to celebrate death days.

This question may seem little bit strange though, as by celebrate I means, calling people on that particular day giving food to all of those who are present there, even a young imam (it means a young guy studying under an imam) or imam will be present there for praying for the dead.

Honestly the gathering over these kind of places I hardly or you can say 99% of them may not grieve for the dead, and on the other side all are laughing, having food something like a mini wedding party.

Also I find on the 3rd day after death a similar kind of party you can find among few Muslims, then after 14 or 17th day followed after 40 days and to yearly basis.

Is there any Islamic backing for the above mentioned action?

Comment: Please note that many rituals are often made up under the influence of local customs and traditions. But, if you're donating to the poor on behalf of the deceased, then I think it could be helpful, but I'm not sure though.

Comment: For your instance, Birthdays are Makruh, according to Dr Zakir Naik. I just wanted to tell you that.

Answer (score 1):

```
              In the name of Allah, the most compassionate, the most merciful
```

As much as I searched, there couldn’t seem to be such days like 3th, 40th (from the view of Shia Islam). But as you mentioned, it is seen that some people do it as if it is a ritual item (based on Islam order!). There couldn’t be any related days as I made research. But it could be Okay and appropriate if we do it in order to reciting the Qur'an and doing some positive/Mustahab (recommended) practices such as charitable deeds. (By paying heed to this issue that it is recommended in several hadiths to send gift for the dead.)

As well as mentioned issues, for instance I see in such religious ceremonies (e.g. in Shia Islam's, perhaps Sunni Islam do so too), the host/family of the dead distribute foods such as date and etc. then commonly the ones who eat them then recite FATHA (Surah Fatiha and and surahs such as Ikhlas) by the intention of dead. Meanwhile, in such ceremonies, the Quran(s) are distributed between individuals and they recite Quran and they dedicate its thawab --reward-- to the dead. Hence such profitable acts can be good if is done by the intention of pleasing God --and actually a kind of helping the dead by doing good deeds/duas--.

On the other hand, these kinds of the rituals will be related to tranquility and condolence for the family of the dead. But we should not do it as a Bid’ah (as if is the order of Islam).

---

**Reference:**

- [www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/50827)
- [www.porseman.org](http://www.porseman.org/q/vservice.aspx?logo=images/right.jpg&id=128806)

Comment: no..what you mean by `But it could be Okay and appropriate if we do it in order to reciting Quran and doing some positive practice` ?

It will considered as bid'a . sure about that

Comment: Dear saleem ahmed, firstly I appreciate you for paying heed to the issue. Secondly: I added at the end of my response that: "But we should not do it as a Bid’ah" / Hence it would be nice By Observing This Item. / Namely: It would be haram if we do these acts as if are based on Islam orders (as Bid'ah), _________ But it can be useful if do these meeting in order to reciting Quran and such items (in order to give its thatwab or reward for the person who have died.

Comment: Otherwise we can call many of our positive repeated acts as Bid'ah, but we cannot call every good act as Bid'ah.___ e.g. : we appoint to have "Quran reciting meetings every Thursday at 22:00 o'clock (by the intention of giving its reciting thawab to our dead parents... ", So, we cannot call it as a Bid'ah by justifying that Islam has not mentioned to have "Quran reciting meetings every Thursday at 22:00 o'clock" , So, we do it just by the intention of thawab. It would be haram if we attribute it to the order of Islam ... / Anyway, thanks for mentioning that. Good luck dear mate.

Comment: Oh yes dear brother.. i just saw that now...sorry for that. please dont keep in mind.